# Access denied on folders for users though they have the rwx permission on SUSE Linux

Tags: permissions, acl

I have a folder /PPI/production/PDF_plan/ on SLES 12 SP1 system. Please find the details below.

```
SERVER1:~ # getfacl /PPI/production/PDF_plan/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: PPI/production/PDF_plan/
# owner: ppi
# group: ppi
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

Then I gave rwx permission for a group called **AdCNC** as below

```
SERVER1:~ # setfacl -Rdm g:AdCNC:rwx /PPI/production/PDF_plan/
SERVER1:~ #
```

**ncaps1** is a user under **AdCNC** group.

```
SERVER1:~ # grep ncaps1 /etc/group
AdCNC:x:1005:ncaps1
SERVER1:~ #
```

Please find below the getfacl output on this folder now. It clearly shows that AdCNC group now has the rwx permission on this folder.

```
SERVER1:~ #
SERVER1:~ # getfacl /PPI/production/PDF_plan/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: PPI/production/PDF_plan/
# owner: ppi
# group: ppi
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:AdCNC:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

But When I try to create a folder or write a file on /PPI/production/PDF_plan/ I am getting 'Permission denied' error message.

```
SERVER1:~ # su ncaps1
ncaps1@SERVER1:/root> cp /Ran/ExistingConfiguration/smb.conf /PPI/production/PDF_plan/
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/PPI/production/PDF_plan/smb.conf’: Permission denied
ncaps1@SERVER1:/root> mkdir /PPI/production/PDF_plan/TestFolder 
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/PPI/production/PDF_plan/TestFolder’: Permission denied
ncaps1@SERVER1:/root>
```

Please help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of executing:

```
setfacl -Rdm g:AdCNC:rwx /PPI/production/PDF_plan/
```

Execute:

```
setfacl -Rm g:AdCNC:rwx /PPI/production/PDF_plan/
```

With the `d` you are applying to default. The output of:

```
getfacl /PPI/production/PDF_plan/
```

Should be:

```
SERVER1: ~ # getfacl /PPI/production/PDF_plan/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: PPI/production/PDF_plan/
# owner: ppi
# group: ppi
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:AdCNC:rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

For more information please see the [POSIX Access Control Lists on Linux](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/usenix03/tech/freenix03/full_papers/gruenbacher/gruenbacher.pdf) whitepaper put together by Andreas Grünbacher of the SuSE Labs.